# Selecionar apenas os primeiros filhos de um elemento pai

Tags: css, seletores

Tenho a seguinte marcação:

```
     <div class="step-content">
        <div id="step-1">
            <h1>step 1</h1>
            <h1>step 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="step-2">
            <h1>step 2</h1>
            <h1>step 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="step-3">
            <h1>step 3</h1>
            <h1>step 3</h1>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Nesse exemplo preciso selecionar apenas os elementos `#step-1`, `#step-2` e `#step-3` para setar `display:none` em cada um deles e não em seu parente (`.step-content`).

> Acima utilizei `div` e `id` sequencial, porém, o seletor não deve depender do tipo do elemento (`div`, `section`, `p` e etc) e nem de seu `id` ou `class`

Qual seletor devo usar para selecionar todos os primeiros nós que são filhos de `.step-content` independente do elemento HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer utilizar só `css`, o truque é usar o `>`:

```
.step-content > * {
    display: none;
}
```

Se você quiser trabalhar com jQuery:

Pra isso você pode utilizar o [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/). Exemplo:

```
$('.step-content').children()
```

Retorno:

`[<div id=​"step-1">​…​</div>​, <div id=​"step-2">​…​</div>​, <div id=​"step-3">​…​</div>​]`

Comment: Isso! havia esquecido desse seletor css. Com javascript puro também poderia ter usado a propriedade `document.querySelector('.step-content').children // [<div id=​"step-1">​…​</div>​, <div id=​"step-2">​…​</div>​, <div id=​"step-3">​…​</div>​]`